# how to stream a video from raspberry pi to amazon web services s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am doing a small mini project to understand the services of amazon web service. I have raspberry pi zero with pi camera attached to it and i want to stream live video from raspberry pi to AWS s3 bucket. Please can anyone guide me how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it to Kinesis Video Stream and it can store it to S3.

Here is the tutorial from AWS,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producersdk-cpp-rpi.html

Deliver video to S3 from kinesis video streams,

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/analyze-live-video-at-scale-in-real-time-using-amazon-kinesis-video-streams-and-amazon-sagemaker/

**EDIT1:**

**Upload with Single or MultiPart Uploads to S3:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

You can do it via cli, programmatically using any of the supported SDK's eaily, or via REST. Choose the SDK based on the needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much let me check it!!

Comment: can i use Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose which directly sends data to AWS S3 or it is not for sending live streaming videos? i'm skeptical about how to send data to S3 please can you guide me. Thanks

Comment: Sending Data to S3 is no different than sending a normal file. S3 also supports multipart upload in chunks. Kinesis Video Streams uses S3 as underlying storage to store video streams. I think that should suffice your need without with a stream or without a stream (sending in chunks).

Comment: please share a link of what you said, or any link which will help me in saving data on S3. Thanks

Comment: I am streaming video from raspberry pi to amazon kinesis video stream (this part is done). Now i want to send video to AWS Rekognition and perform face detection on the live video. Kindly answer in detail and with links. Thankyou!

Comment: Please do some more research and try to implement, if you have got issues please post as question to stackoverflow.